# sql select with does not contain

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my select:

```
select MY_ID, JOB_ID
from MY_TABLE
where JOB_ID != 'bra%'
and JOB_ID != 'wes%'
and STS_DTTM < trunc (sysdate) -12
```

It still selects fields with values that contain "bra" and "wes"

Thank you & regards,

Answer (score 11):

Should be:

```
select MY_ID, JOB_ID
from MY_TABLE
where JOB_ID not like 'bra%'
and JOB_ID not like 'wes%'
and STS_DTTM < trunc (sysdate) - 12;
```

And the column name should be job_name or job_code, not Job_id. Job_id sounds like a number :)

Comment: thanks everyone for the assistance. yes the column names was only a example. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

use NOT LIKE instead of !=

```
select MY_ID, JOB_ID
from MY_TABLE
where JOB_ID NOT LIKE'bra%'
and JOB_ID NOT LIKE 'wes%'
and STS_DTTM < trunc (sysdate) -12
```

Answer (score 1):

I'am not sure, but this SQL request might works:

```
    select MY_ID, JOB_ID
    from MY_TABLE
    where NOT (JOB_ID LIKE 'bra%' OR JOB_ID LIKE 'wes%')
    and STS_DTTM < trunc (sysdate) -12
```